# Prevent Client-Side Storage of XMLHttpRequest Documents

Tags: javascript, xml, caching, internet-explorer-8, client-side

I've written some JavaScript that uses XMLHttpRequest to fetch a large amount of XML documents from a remote server. To do this, I've created a variable that the response of my request is stored in. I parse each response for the data I'm interested it. Then, I loop back and run the function again, with a different URL. My understanding was that because I used the same variable to store the XML, each document would overwrite the one before it. However, Windows Task Manger reveals that the memory used by Internet Explorer continues to grow, presumably from cached versions of the now-meaningless documents.

How can I prevent IE from storing all of the documents? Is there a way to clear this cache every now and then?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that. IE is storing each response data in his cache. You don't have to handle this cache, let IE do that for you.

Comment: Will it automatically clear this every so often? Because we're talking 12 GB of data.

Comment: IE will receive a clear request from Windows before RAM will be full. The memory usage differs from navigators, certain will retain, other not...

Comment: Probably you may be able to set the HTTP Header so it does not cache in the responses ?

Comment: In the request I specify `req.setRequestHeader( "pragma", "no-cache" );` but that doesn't seem to do anything. Internet Explorer is currently at 99,908K and counting. EDIT: I got the "Out of Memory" error at about 122,000K.

Comment: Can you append a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to each request you send to try preventing cache ? Like : http://google.com?_=20110726195307123

Comment: I've seen that suggested, but every URL I request is different already.

Comment: And can you reload the page where you are and continue calling urls by packet ?

Comment: I'm requesting several million XML documents, but I can get to about 40,000 before I run out of memory. It would be a real pain, but it might be my only choice.

Comment: I have a partial fix: I moved `var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();` out of the recursive function to avoid creating an endless number of objects. Memory usage is now under control. However, I'm still getting `Out of memory` errors.